# SQLITE Join on Date = Date + x

Tags: sqlite, date, join

I am using the following insert query to create a comparison between two tables using the dates to join on.

```
INSERT INTO Comp_Table (Date, CKROne, CKRTwo, ChangeOne, ChangeTwo, State) 
SELECT BaseTbl.Date, BaseTbl.CKR, CompTbl.CKR, BaseTbl.Change, CompTbl.Change, 
CASE 
WHEN BaseTbl.Change > 0 AND CompTbl.Change > 0 THEN 'positive' 
WHEN BaseTbl.Change < 0 AND CompTbl.Change < 0 THEN 'positive' 
ELSE 'inversely' 
END AS 'Correlation' 
FROM BaseTbl 
JOIN CompTbl ON BaseTbl.Date = CompTbl.Date;
```

This works well.  However, I would like to be able to join the tables with a lag. As in, the user can define if they want to do exact match on dates or if they want to use a date of one's occurrence plus a number and return the value from the latter date for comparison to the number to the former date.  Pseudo code example:

User sets variable = 0 then

```
Join ComTbl On BaseTbl.Date = CompTbl.Date + 0;
```

User sets variable = 7 then

```
Join CompTbl On BaseTbl.Date = CompTbl.Date + 7; 
(joins 2012-01-01 from BaseTbl to 2012-01-08 from CompTbl)
```

I tried to add days like you would in a Where clause ('+7 day'), but this didn't work.  I also tried to using a Where clause with `BaseTbl.Date = CompTbl.Date '+ 7 day'` but that returned a 0 value also.  How can this be accomplished in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `DATE()` function to build the `WHERE` clause you want:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ...
FROM BaseTbl
INNER JOIN ComTbl
    ON BaseTbl.Date = DATE(CompTbl.Date, '7 days')
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!